# Extracting elements from a character vector that contain specific character parts

Tags: r

In the following vector:

```
x<-c("*D46*E146*N189", "*M420", "*B491*K380", "*Y841*N189*N179", "*K389*E142X")
```

I would like to extract the elements that contain `"E14"` and `"K38"`.

That is, I would like to have returned the elements: `"*D46*E146*N189"`, `"*B491*K380"`, and `"*K389*E142X"`.

Does anyone have any suggestion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `grep`

```
> grep("E14|K38", x, value = TRUE)
[1] "*D46*E146*N189" "*B491*K380"     "*K389*E142X"
```

Or indexing using R base `grep` or `grepl`

```
x[grep("E14|K38", x)]
x[grepl("E14|K38", x)]
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use `str_detect`

```
library(stringr)
x[str_detect(x, "E14|K38")]
#[1] "*D46*E146*N189" "*B491*K380"     "*K389*E142X"
```